# Cloning a Jquery draggable also drags its original

Tags: jquery, clone, draggable

I am creating an activity generator authoring tool. The user, using a right click menu can choose to add a number of elements to the page, and for some of them, fill them with text.

Using Jquery UI, All elements are draggable and some are resizeable. I want the user to be able to make an exact copy of an element but when I use the clone function i'm getting strange results. I can drag the original away from the clone but when I try to drag the clone, it just drags the original around and stays in its place.

Heres my code

```
    function addobject (element_type){
       $('#activitystage').append($("<div class=\"draggable " + element_type + "\" id=\"" + counter + "\"></div>")); 
       $( "#" + counter ).multidraggable({ containment: "#activitystage",  grid: [10, 10],drag: function(event,ui){ showpositions(); }});   
       $('#' + counter).contextMenu({menu: 'functionsMenu'  }, function(action, el, pos) {run(action, el);  });
       $('#' + counter).append("<textarea class=\"" + element_type + "\"></textarea>");
    }

    function run (action, el){
       switch (action){
            case "clone":
              $(el).clone(true).attr('id', 'some new id').appendTo('#activitystage');
              break;
}
```

Comment: have you tried to reaply the multidraggable function on the cloned div ?

Comment: What version of jQuery are you using?

Comment: Also, if `counter` is a number then you appear to have invalid HTML.  IDs cannot start with a number.

Comment: I'm using jquery 1.5, jquery ui 1.8. Didnt know you can't start an ID with a number, thanks. Tried reapplying multidraggable but that didn't help

Comment: try clone(false).attr('id', 'sfsds').multidraggable()

Comment: If you clone an object, usually makes a shallow copy. Any properties that are references to other variables, will remain references. You have to set the draggable to the new object

Answer (score 0):

The easiest fix for your problem i can think of is to simply use clone(false) and rebind the drag and drop event.

Try this code

```
var attr = { containment: "#activitystage",  grid: [10, 10],drag: function(event,ui){ showpositions(); }};

function addobject (element_type){
    $('#activitystage').append($("<div class=\"draggable " + element_type + "\" id=\"" + counter + "\"></div>")); 
    $( "#" + counter ).multidraggable(attr);   
    $('#' + counter).contextMenu({menu: 'functionsMenu'  }, function(action, el, pos) {run(action, el);  });
    $('#' + counter).append("<textarea class=\"" + element_type + "\"></textarea>");
}

    function run (action, el){
       switch (action){
            case "clone":
              $(el).clone(false).attr('id', 'some new id').appendTo('#activitystage').multidraggable(attr);
              break;
}
```